# Вывести строку в обратном порядке, при этом сохраняя цельность слов с++

Tags: c++, массивы, строки, char

Например, есть строка Hello World, нужно вывести World Hello. Получается только dlrow olleh. Помогите, пожалуйста, решить задачу максимально простым языком, так как изучаю с++ всего месяц.

```
char str[255];
    char str1[255];
    gets(str);
    cout<<endl;
    int len=strlen(str);
    cout<<"текст в обратном порядке:"<<endl;

    for(int i=len-1; i>=0; i--)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<=len-1; i++)
        {
            if (str[len-1]!=' ')
            str[i]=str1[len];
        }
    }
        for(int i=0; i<=len-1; i++)
        {
            if(str[len]==' ')
                
            str[len-i]
        }
```

Comment: Воспользоваться стеком (`stack<string>`) - это разрешено? Или вектором, что, в общем-то, то жэе самое :)

Comment: Нет, такого еще не знаю. И про вектор тоже еще не рассказывали(

Comment: читаете слова по одному начиная с хвоста. Переворачиваете. Выводите. Идёте дальше.

Comment: без кода не понимаю(

Comment: Покажите, как сделали, чтобы было проще подсказать

Comment: Добавила ответ ниже

Comment: Ну это не ответ, нужно было отредактировать вопрос, добавив код туда. А по сути - вместо того, чтобы копировать каждый символ, копируйте сразу слово, начиная с запомненной позиции, когда встретите пробел. А позицию начала слова запоминайте, когда встретите первый не пробел.

Comment: Это я понимаю, можете показать кусочек кода каким образом можно реализовать именно "запоминание" слова от точки "отсчета" пока я не встречу пробел. И потом все запомненные слова разместить в обратном порядке. Именно это вводит меня в ступор, так как не могу понять как это сделать.